# AWS API Gateway VTL Include Source API JSON in Response Template

Tags: json, aws-api-gateway, velocity, vtl

We would like to include the Integration/Source API JSON in the response, but when we attempt to include the Object, it does not encode properly.

```
    "success": true,
    "message": "Resource Call Made Successfully",
    "data": {ip=127.0.0.1, ipv4=127.0.0.1, ipv6=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, asn=null, asn_name=null, country=US, useragent={family=Other...
```

As you can see, the strings lose their quotes; breaking the JSON. Here's the template;

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path("$"))
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Resource Call Made Successfully",
    "data": $inputRoot
}
```

I've tried using `$json.parse(), escaping, etc` with no luck. Anyone familiar enough to give some direction on how to stringify this so I can include it in the response?

Answer (score 0):

Use syntax like below,

```
"subject": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.path('$.Attributes.subject.S')).replaceAll(\"\\\\'\",\"'\")"
```

It's an explanation in [$util.escapeJavaScript() function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference)